# Prove the graph with $11$ vertices (each one of degree $\ge 5$) must be connected.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Prove any graph with $11$ vertices (each one of degree $\ge 5$) must be connected.

The following is not a proof, just an outline of what I am thinking.

Let's call the given graph $G.$ We know that a graph or its complement must be connected. So we must prove that the complement of $G$ must be disconnected. Since the smallest degree of $G$ is $5$ and the largest possible degree is $10,$ the degree sequence of $G$ is $(5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10).$ Then we can use the Degree Sequence Algorithm to find the complement of $G$ and conclude (hope) it's disconnected.

Does the outline above make sense? Honestly, I have no idea how to find the degree sequence of $G.$ Would what I did work or how do I fix it? Also, is there a simpler way? Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling that the graph must also be simple?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Yes, it should be simple, since $K_5\cup K_6$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for a proof by contradiction. Assume the graph is not connected. Then you have at least 2 subgraphs.

Let us consider the least number of vertices these subgraphs must have. Since each of the vertices have a degree of at least $5$, this means that each subgraph must have at least $6$ vertices.

But there are only $11$ vertices which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I accept both answers. I saw your answer first.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for a contradiction that $G$ is not connected. Then it has at least $2$ connected components, say  $V_{1}$ and  $V_{2}$. With $\mid V_{1}\mid + \mid V_{2}\mid = 11$.

Therefore $\mid V_{1}\mid \leq 5$ or $\mid V_{2}\mid \leq 5$, contradicting that the minimum degree is $ \geq5$.